# How to display the values in powershell in Excel format

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I have got certian output of list properties using powershell script. I need to display it in an excel format. I require the code to display the result in excel format?

Comment: Can you try to elaborate what you mean with Excel format, and what is the data that you need to display?

Comment: Whatever output i get i need to export it to excel and show it to user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be as easy as piping your output object to `| Export-Csv -NoType fileName.csv`

So for example:

```
Get-SPSite http://* | Export-Csv -NoType fileName.csv
```

This will give you a .csv file that is openable in Excel

Comment: Hi, The command which you have provided is only for retreving the site url and displaying in excel i guess. I requite all list names from a site colelction to be exported  in excel. (I have already done with the code for retrevign all list from site collection but am struck with exporting those list names to excel.

Comment: I asked you what was the information you needed to show, you gave me an answer saying "any information", I showed you how to pipe output to a csv. The rest is up to you :)